# Tetris code for pieces and map

Tags: c, game, tetris

I'm making a simple Tetris clone and would like to know how's my code for the map and pieces. I'm using `x`, `y`, `x_before`, `y_before`, `t0`, `t1` to allow smooth movement.

**colors.h**

```
#ifndef TETRIS_COLORS_H
#define TETRIS_COLORS_H

typedef enum {
    DARK_CYAN, DARK_RED, DARK_BROWN, DARK_MAGENTA, 
    DARK_GRAY, DARK_GREEN, DARK_BLUE, WALL, EMPTY
} Color;

#endif
```

**pieces.h**

```
#ifndef TETRIS_PIECES_H
#define TETRIS_PIECES_H

#include "colors.h"
#include "map.h"
#include "definitions.h"

#define PIECE_COUNT 7
#define PIECE_ROWS 4
#define PIECE_COLUMNS 4
#define PIECE_POINTS (PIECE_ROWS * PIECE_COLUMNS)
#define PIECE_BLOCKS_SIZE 4

typedef struct {
    int n;
    int matrix[4][16];
    Color color;
    int x;
    int y;
    int x_before;
    int y_before;
    unsigned int t0;
    unsigned int t1;
} Piece;

void piece_rotate(Piece *piece);
void piece_rotate_backwards(Piece *piece);
void piece_random(Piece *dest);
void piece_new(Piece *piece);
void piece_draw(Map *map, Piece *piece);
int piece_valid_position(Map *map, Piece *piece);

#endif
```

**pieces.c**

```
#include "pieces.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

Piece i = {0, 

    0, 0, 0, 0,
    1, 1, 1, 1,
    0, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0,

    0, 0, 1, 0,
    0, 0, 1, 0,
    0, 0, 1, 0,
    0, 0, 1, 0,

    0, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0,
    1, 1, 1, 1,
    0, 0, 0, 0,

    0, 1, 0, 0,
    0, 1, 0, 0,
    0, 1, 0, 0,
    0, 1, 0, 0

, DARK_CYAN, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};



Piece j = {0,

    1, 0, 0, 0,
    1, 1, 1, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0,

    0, 1, 1, 0,
    0, 1, 0, 0,
    0, 1, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0,

    0, 0, 0, 0,
    1, 1, 1, 0,
    0, 0, 1, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0,

    0, 1, 0, 0,
    0, 1, 0, 0,
    1, 1, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0
, DARK_RED, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};


Piece l = {0,

    0, 0, 1, 0,
    1, 1, 1, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0,

    0, 1, 0, 0,
    0, 1, 0, 0,
    0, 1, 1, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0,

    0, 0, 0, 0,
    1, 1, 1, 0,
    1, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0,

    1, 1, 0, 0,
    0, 1, 0, 0,
    0, 1, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0

, DARK_BROWN, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};

Piece o = {0,

    0, 1, 1, 0,
    0, 1, 1, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0,

    0, 1, 1, 0,
    0, 1, 1, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0,

    0, 1, 1, 0,
    0, 1, 1, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0,

    0, 1, 1, 0,
    0, 1, 1, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0

, DARK_MAGENTA, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};

Piece s = {0,

    0, 1, 1, 0,
    1, 1, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0,

    0, 1, 0, 0,
    0, 1, 1, 0,
    0, 0, 1, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0,

    0, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 1, 1, 0,
    1, 1, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0,

    1, 0, 0, 0,
    1, 1, 0, 0,
    0, 1, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0

, DARK_GRAY, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};

Piece t = {0,

    0, 1, 0, 0,
    1, 1, 1, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0,

    0, 1, 0, 0,
    0, 1, 1, 0,
    0, 1, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0,

    0, 0, 0, 0,
    1, 1, 1, 0,
    0, 1, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0,

    0, 1, 0, 0,
    1, 1, 0, 0,
    0, 1, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0
, DARK_GREEN, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};

Piece z = {0,

    1, 1, 0, 0,
    0, 1, 1, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0,

    0, 0, 1, 0,
    0, 1, 1, 0,
    0, 1, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0,

    0, 0, 0, 0,
    1, 1, 0, 0,
    0, 1, 1, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0,

    0, 1, 0, 0,
    1, 1, 0, 0,
    1, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0

, DARK_BLUE, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};

Piece *piece_list[PIECE_COUNT] = {&i, &j, &l, &o, &s, &t, &z};



void piece_rotate(Piece *piece)
{
    piece->n = ++piece->n % 4;
}

void piece_rotate_backwards(Piece *piece)
{
    piece->n = (--piece->n > -1) ? piece->n : 3;
}

void piece_random(Piece *dest)
{
    memcpy(dest, piece_list[rand() % PIECE_COUNT], sizeof(Piece)-sizeof(int) * 4);
}

void piece_new(Piece *piece)
{
    piece_random(piece);
    piece->x_before = piece->x = 1 + (GAME_COLUMNS - 2 - PIECE_BLOCKS_SIZE) / 2;
    piece->y_before = piece->y = 1;
    piece->t0 = piece->t1 = 0;
}

void piece_draw(Map *map, Piece *piece)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < PIECE_BLOCKS_SIZE * PIECE_BLOCKS_SIZE; ++i)
        if(piece->matrix[piece->n][i])
            map_draw_block( map, 
                            piece->y + i / PIECE_BLOCKS_SIZE, 
                            piece->x + i % PIECE_BLOCKS_SIZE, 
                            piece->color                    );
}

int piece_valid_position(Map *map, Piece *piece)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < PIECE_BLOCKS_SIZE * PIECE_BLOCKS_SIZE; ++i)
        if(piece->matrix[piece->n][i])
            if(map_block_at(    map, 
                                piece->y + i / PIECE_BLOCKS_SIZE, 
                                piece->x + i % PIECE_BLOCKS_SIZE    )
                            != EMPTY)
                return 0;

    return 1;
}
```

**map.h**

```
#ifndef TETRIS_MAP_H
#define TETRIS_MAP_H

#include "colors.h"

typedef struct Map {
    Color *blocks;
    int rows;
    int columns;
} Map;

Map *map_create(int rows, int columns);
void map_delete(Map *map);
void map_clear(Map *map);
void map_add_wall(Map *map);
Color map_block_at(Map *map, int row, int column);
void map_draw_block(Map *map, int row, int column, Color block);
void map_clear_row(Map *map, int row);
void move_rows_down(Map *map, int bottom_y);

#endif
```

**map.c**

```
#include "map.h"
#include <stdlib.h>

Map *map_create(int new_rows, int new_columns)
{
    Map *map = malloc(sizeof(Map) + sizeof(Color) * new_rows * new_columns);
    if(map == NULL)
        return NULL;

    map->blocks = (Color *)(map + 1);
    map->rows = new_rows;
    map->columns = new_columns;

    return map;
}

void map_delete(Map *map)
{
    free(map);
}

void map_clear(Map *map)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < map->rows * map->columns; ++i)
        map->blocks[i] = EMPTY;
}

void map_add_wall(Map *map)
{
    //Top
    for(int i = 0; i < map->columns; ++i)
        map->blocks[i] = WALL;

    //Bottom
    for(int i = 0; i < map->columns; ++i)
        map->blocks[(map->rows -1) * map->columns + i] = WALL;

    //Left and right
    for(int i = 1; i < map->rows; ++i){
        map->blocks[i * map->columns - 1] = WALL;
        map->blocks[i * map->columns] = WALL;
    }
}

Color map_block_at(Map *map, int row, int column)
{
    return map->blocks[row * map->columns + column];
}

void map_draw_block(Map *map, int row, int column, Color block)
{
    map->blocks[row * map->columns + column] = block;
}

void map_clear_row(Map *map, int row)
{
    for(int x = 1; x < map->columns - 1; ++x)
        map->blocks[row * map->columns + x] = EMPTY;
}

void move_rows_down(Map *map, int bottom_y)
{
    for(int y = bottom_y; y > 1; --y)
        for(int x = 1; x < map->columns - 1; ++x)
            map_draw_block(map, y, x, map_block_at(map, y - 1, x));

    map_clear_row(map, 1);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Overall this looks very nice.  It's easy to read, and is very refined.  A few notes:

- You can remove the `Map` from the first line of your structure.

  ```
  typedef struct
  {
      Color *blocks;
      int rows;
      int columns;
  } Map;
  ```
- Your function `map_delete()` only performs one action, freeing the memory of `map`.  Unless you plan to expand on the `map` structure where you will have to free more members within the structure itself, I would get rid of it and just call `free(map)`.  If you have compiler optimizations on, I guarantee that your compiler is already doing that for you anyways, so it should slightly decrease compilation time.
- You can simpilfy your `NULL` tests.

  ```
  if(!map)
  ```
- This is more of a style issue, but since this recently led to the [Apple `goto` security flaw](http://nakedsecurity.sophos.com/2014/02/24/anatomy-of-a-goto-fail-apples-ssl-bug-explained-plus-an-unofficial-patch/), I'm going to cover it.  I don't think you are writing your brace-free single statement loops and test conditionals correctly.  This is completely up to you to decide since [this is a style issue](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/16530/94014), but I prefer to do it like this:

  ```
  if(!map) return NULL;
  ```

  Other's may be more strict and tell you to use braces, but it's up to you.
- You need more comments.  There are some lines in your code that I have trouble following.  And if I have trouble following it, chances are that you will have trouble following it as well when you re-visit this project in a few months.  Save yourself (and possibly others) the trouble and document your code.